# Excel Chart Not Recognized as Chart in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to add a chart in VBA but in my workbook it is recognizing my chart as a sheet. How do I save Sheet2 as a chart recognizable by VBA?

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to convert `Sheet2` which is a `Worksheet` to a chart?

Comment: the title of your question and the actual question do not match

Comment: @BrandonBarney - yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say, "but in my workbook it is recognizing my chart as a sheet".  You may have some confusion over the 2 common kinds of charts in Excel: Charts which are on their own separate sheet, and Chart objects which are embedded in a regular worksheet.  If you place some data in Columns A and B of a Worksheet named "Sheet1", the code below will make a chart object in that sheet, and then move it to it's own Chart sheet, and then move it back to Sheet1 again.  If this doesn't address your question, please provide more detail.

```
Option Explicit
Sub chartTypes()
Dim r As Range, chObj As ChartObject, sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set r = sh.UsedRange
Set chObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
  With chObj
    .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=r
    'move chart to a chart sheet
    .Chart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
  End With
ActiveSheet.Name = "newChart"
'move chart back to sheet
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=sh.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, this is perfect!

Comment: Sub createmychart()
Dim chart1 As Chart
Set chart1 = Charts.Add
chart1.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, PlotBy:=xlColumns
chart1.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

End Sub